# How to create new user with Public key authentication?

Tags: ssh, users, user-management, adduser, useradd

I have Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS. I have Public key authentication enabled by default.

I used the following command to create new user:

```
sudo useradd -m -c "John T." john -s /bin/bash
```

The command apparently created user, user's home folder... but obviously user cannot log in, because user does not have a key. What's next? How to create key and attach it to the user?

```
-c -- User's full name
-m -- Creates user's home directory
-s -- Specify user's login shell
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to store his public key in `~john/.ssh/authorized_keys` as described in manual page for `sshd` (good place to start). Also you need to make sure the `~john/.ssh/` directory is owned by `john` and has `0700` permissions and `~john/.ssh/authorized_keys` also with permissions `0600`.

Then the user should be able to log in.